# SharePoint 2013 development from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, 2013, visual-studio-2012, standalone

Do I need to install VS 2012 after SP 2012. I don't see SP 2013 Project options only SP 2010. I install VS 2012 before SP 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apps/fp123627.aspx). This will add the "traditional" SharePoint 2013 project options as well as the ability to create app projects for Office 2013 and SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Thank you.. and this is on MS, but I am completely confused with install options on that page.  I already have SP 2013 Standalone and VS 2012. Can you send me the link to the actual download in question? Do I have Sign up to download?

Comment: Sure, it's the "Download the tools" link for the Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012 that points here: http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx?command=GetInstallerRedirect&appid=OfficeToolsForVS2012GA

Comment: Thank you this seems to have worked. I was able to build a new app with NAPA and open it locally with vs2012, edit it and deploy it back up.  But if I try to deploy a new sp app to SPO it says 'slideloading apps is not enabled'. Also, where do I change the target SPO location once it's been set intiatially.. I've looked everywhere. I'm going to create a new question for these and other spo 2013 dev questions. Thanks.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58697/spo-2013-and-vs-2012-deployment-noob-questions